# Select a table cell if it has a comment node containing a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need to test if the second cell of any rows with attribute `section-name = section2` and second cell containing '`FieldInternalName="BaseLineEUI`" ' in the comment node - is empty or not? I simply gave up after this:

```
jQ("tr[section-name='Section2']").each(function(i){
$(this).children('td').slice(0,2).
 //how do I test if the comment contains a string here?

})
```

---

```
<tr style="display: block;" section-name="Section2">
      <TD class=ms-formlabel vAlign=top width=165 noWrap>
      <H3 class=ms-standardheader>
      <A name=SPBookmark_ClimateZoneASHRAEIECC></A>ClimateZoneASHRAEIECC</H3>
      </TD>
      <TD id=SPFieldText class=ms-formbody vAlign=top width=450>
      <!-- FieldName="ClimateZoneASHRAEIECC"  
          FieldInternalName="ClimateZoneASHRAEIECC" FieldType="SPFieldText" -->&nbsp; 
       </TD>    
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: block;" section-name="Section2">
      <TD class=ms-formlabel vAlign=top width=165 noWrap>
      <H3 class=ms-standardheader>
      <A name=SPBookmark_BaselineEUI></A>BaselineEUI</H3>
     </TD>
      <TD id=SPFieldNumber class=ms-formbody vAlign=top width=450>
      <!-- FieldName="BaselineEUI"  FieldInternalName="BaselineEUI" 
       FieldType="SPFieldNumber" -->&nbsp; 
     </TD>
    </tr>
```

Comment: How should be the empty comment node? `<!-- -->` like this? and btw, you have a very odd requirement..

Comment: So what do you want to do with these rows, or cells if they have/do not have a comment node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest (given the requirements and hideous, *hideous* HTML):

```
// selects those 'td' elements that are the second child (:nth-child(2))
// of their parent 'tr' element with a 'section-name' attribute that is
// equal to 'Section2', and filters that collection:
$("tr[section-name='Section2'] td:nth-child(2)").filter(function(){

    // we retain only those 'td' elements with at least one childNode
    // that is a comment-node (nodeType === 8) and contains the string
    // supplied to 'indexOf()'
    return $(this).contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType === 8 && this.nodeValue.indexOf('FieldInternalName="BaselineEUI"') > -1;
    // if there is a length (IE there was more than zero matching
    // nodes found) we retain the 'td' element we're filtering
    }).length;
// moving to the previous 'td' element, and using 'css()' to color its text red:
}).prev('td').css('color', 'red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kQ644/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
  - [CSS Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
  - [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).
  - `String.indexOf()`.
- jQuery:

  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Comment: The way you wrote it is beautiful,and nicely explained. But it doesn't seem to do what I envision. I want to basically highlight the text of the first cell to red with the above matching condition if the second cell with above matching condition (i.e its comments containing the string") is empty text(). This is where I am at: >>jQ("tr[section-name='Section2']").each(function(i){
 if ($(this).children('td').eq(1).html().indexOf("BaselineEUI") >= 0){
   $(this).children('td').eq(0).hide();
 }
   
})

Comment: I'm glad! Though I'd really *really* **really** ***really*** recommend you stop letting MS Word(?) -at a guess- generate HTML for you. It's *horrible*.

Comment: It's actually a SharePoint site, which is no better .. But thank you much!